# jQuery click event not firing. Odd results

Tags: jquery, onclick

So I have this click event:

```
$(".pickerOpt").click(function() { 
    $(this).child('span').show();
});
```

and this:

```
<ul id="hair" class="picker">
<span>Hair</span>
    <li id="a" class="pickerOpt"><span>.</span></li>
    <li id="b" class="pickerOpt"><span>.</span></li>
    <li id="c" class="pickerOpt"><span>.</span></li>
    <li id="d" class="pickerOpt"><span>.</span></li>
    <li id="e" class="pickerOpt"><span>.</span></li>
    <li id="f" class="pickerOpt"><span>.</span></li>
</ul>
<ul id="eye" class="picker">
    <span>Eyes</span>
    <li id="g" class="pickerOpt"><span>.</span></li>
    <li id="h" class="pickerOpt"><span>.</span></li>
    <li id="i" class="pickerOpt"><span>.</span></li>
    <li id="j" class="pickerOpt"><span>.</span></li>
</ul>
```

By default the span is hidden, when I click the li (now a swaure looking block element) I want it to show it, but its not working. I set the click event to a h2 I had and it actually worked when i through a console.log("derp derp") on it, but every time I clicked it, it would fire 5 times in the console. I refreshed the page and it wouldn't do it again.

Please help, I gotta pump this site out. Here is the live version: http://scoutsamerica.com/admin/addmodel.php

Comment: there is no such method `.child`. also mention jquery version

Comment: which span is hidden? outside of the  `li` or inside the `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".pickerOpt").unbind().click(function (e) {

//your content here 

}
```

with that you click is bind only for once

Comment: I used a combo of your and diEcho's answers, I will accept yours. Thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `.child()` method in jQuery, what you want is `.children()`

Answer (score 0):

though your question is not clear, AFAIU, try with  >= jQuery 1.7 `.on`

```
$(document).on('click', '.pickerOpt' , function() { 
    $(this).children('span').show();
});
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/6pEsb/2)

Comment: The elements are not dynamically created and the handler is set on dom ready, so delegation will not make any difference.